# Extract key value pair from json column in redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have a table `mytable` that stores columns in the form of `JSON` strings, which contain multiple key-value pairs. Now, I want to extract only a particular value corresponding to one key.
The column that stores these strings is of varchar datatype, and is created as:
`insert into mytable(empid, json_column)  values (1,'{"FIRST_NAME":"TOM","LAST_NAME" :"JENKINS", "DATE_OF_JOINING" :"2021-06-10", "SALARY" :"1000" }').`

As you can see, `json_column` is created by inserting only a string. Now, I want to do something like:
`select json_column.FIRST_NAME from mytable`

I just want to extract the `value` corresponding to key `FIRST_NAME`.
Though my actual table is far more complex than this example, and I cannot convert these `JSON` keys into different columns themselves. But, this example clearly illustrates my issue.
This needs to be done over Redshift, please help me out with any valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using function `json_extract_path_text` of Redshift can solve this problem easily, as follows:

```
select json_extract_path_text(json_column, 'FIRST_NAME') from mytable;
```